# Trying to read data from a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've been trying to read data from a spreadsheet that returns a string based on whether or not the item is in stock or not. I just started this project and haven't compared it to the numeric values, but I'm already running into issues with reading the data and returning a string. Really new to Google script, don't know much about it - any advice would help! Thanks in advance.

```
function OrganizeData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var message = "".toString();

  if (data[2].toString() == "Software" && data[3].toString() == "Garage Band") {
    return message = "Item is available!";

  } else if (data[2].toString() != "Software" && data[3].toString() == "Garage Band") {
    return message = "Current item is out of stock.";

  }
}
```

Comment: What does some of the data look like?

Comment: what do you expect `return message = "some value";` to do? either assign to `message` in your cases and later call `return message;` or call `return "specific text";` directly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are accessing the data set incorrectly. The [.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) method you are calling returns a two-dimensional array of objects and you are only accessing the first dimension of that structure. Unless the concatenation of the entire row/column is the string you are looking for, the initial if statement will fail.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does - I am really new with Google Script, thanks!

Comment: No problem, happy I could help!

Answer (score 0):

With the following sample data:

```
| ID | Name | Type     | Category    | In Stock                      | 
|----|------|----------|-------------|-------------------------------| 
| 1  | Foo  | Software | Garage Band | Item is available!            | 
| 2  | Bar  | Food     | Garage Band | Current item is out of stock. |
```

I was able to add the messages inside the "In Stock" cells.

```js
function showMessage(sheetName, targetCol) {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var row = 1; row < data.length; row++) {
    var productType = data[row][2].toString();
    var productName = data[row][3].toString();
    var message = '';

    if (productType === "Software" && productName === "Garage Band") {
      message = "Item is available!";

    } else if (productType !== "Software" && productName === "Garage Band") {
      message = "Current item is out of stock.";
    }

    sheet.getRange(row + 1, targetCol).setValue(message);
  }
}

function OrganizeData() {
  showMessage('Form Responses 1', 5);
}

// Select `OrganizeData` from drop-down and run program
```

Comment: I'm actually still running into errors while attempting to run the code. I keep getting "You do not have permission to call setValue (line 18)." - the line where 'sheet.getRange(row + 1, targetCol).setValue(message);

Comment: You have to authorize the script to run on your spreadsheet. Also, make sure you are modifying the column.